# Суть композиции

Tags: python, ооп, классы

Композиция (агрегирование) рассматривается в противовес наследованию. Не совсем поняв данное явление в одном источнике, я пошёл на просторы интернета и выяснил, что идея композиции заключается в том, что это соединение отдельных элементов в единое целое, а формально это класс, который использует обьекты другого класса.

Разграничительной чертой между наследованием и композицией является тот факт, что при создании обьекта класса-агрегатора также создаются обьекты агрегируемых классов (надеюсь понятно пишу). В моём понимании, создание обьекта это код формата "переменная = класс(параметры)", а в качестве примера композиции мне давался следующий сниппет:

```py
class Bill():
    def __init__(self, description):
        self.description = description

class Tail():
    def __init__(self, length):
        self.length = length
 
 class Duck():
    def __init__(self, bill, tail):
        self.bill = bill
        self.tail = tail
    def about(self):
        print('This duck has a', bill.description, 'bill and a', tail.length, 'tail')
 
>>> tail = Tail('long')
>>> bill = Bill('wide orange')
>>> duck = Duck(bill, tail)
```

Видно, что при создании обьекта `duck` класса `Duck`, в параметры `bill` и `tail` конструктора передаются одноимённые обьекты, которые затем сохраняютcя в качестве переменных `self.bill` и `self.tail`.

Как я понимаю, это и есть идея композиции: использование кода других классов в классе-агрегаторе через их обьекты. Однако метод `about` обращается не к этим новосозданным атрибутам, а к обьектам агрегируемых классов `bill` и `tail` на основном уровне программы, которые к тому же ещё не созданы на момент завершения написания класса `Duck`.

Так зачем мы передавали обьекты в конструктор, впоследствии создав из них атрибуты, которые не получили дальнейшего применения и идея композиции потерялась? Более того, конструктора могло вообще не существовать для класса `Duck`, а метод about продолжил бы работать как прежде, ведь его содержимое не связано с какими-либо элементами внутри класса.

Comment: Очевидно, что приведённый фрагмент кода просто некорректен. Как уже написали в ответе, в методе about должно быть self.bill.description и self.tail.length

Answer (score 1):

Вы неправильно обращаетесь к полям класса, нужно через `self`.

Не:

```
print('This duck has a', bill.description, 'bill and a', tail.length, 'tail')
```

А:

```
print('This duck has a', self.bill.description, 'bill and a', self.tail.length, 'tail')
```

В текущем варианте вы обращаетесь к глобальным переменным `tail = ...` и `bill =`